# Code error when run outside of Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, project, chatbot

I am creating a very basic, text-based chatbot program (my first program since learning through online courses) in Python that handles various user inputs. I am troubleshooting my own code with Jupiter notebook and my own Terminal. However, the code runs in Jupyter, but not in my own Terminal.

I've tried my own Terminal and my online course's terminal but I keep getting an error on the `response ==`, but maybe it's because I haven't quite learned the nuances of it so maybe that's the problem.

```py
def cs_service_bot():
    print("Hello! I'm the chatbot here! Welcome to my services. Are you a new or existing user?\n\n")
    response = input('Please enter the number corresponding to your choice: ')
    if response == 1:
        new_customer()
    elif response == 2:
        existing_customer()
    else:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand your choice.")
```

Should run but code trips up at `if response == 1:` and so forth.

Comment: which command did you type in your terminal and what is the error message ?

Comment: `input()` returns a string, so you are trying to compare a string to an integer.

Comment: Download PyCharm (or any other IDE) and go away from writing your code in a notebook. You're slowing yourself down with that. Learn how to use a debugger, best advice one can give you at this point.

Comment: @displayname I also use Atom. Should I switch from text editors to IDEs then? I mainly use Atom to store bits of practice code and notes

Comment: Atom is fine too. Never used it myself but writing a chatbot in a jupyter notebook sound to me like a lot of "printf-debuggin". The important thing is the debugger here. Atom has a plugin for that afaik. I always use PyCharm. Whatever floats your boat. (can recommend PyCharm though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` [returns a string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), you are comparing against integers.

Try:

```
print("Hello! I'm the chatbot here! Welcome to my services. Are you a new or existing user?\n\n")
response = input('Please enter the number corresponding to your choice: ')
if response == "1":
    new_customer()
elif response == "2":
    existing_customer()
else:
    print("Sorry, I didn't understand your choice.")
```